# Can I create a TFS branch when I publish?

Tags: asp.net, build, tfs, publish

I am looking for a way to automatically create a branch or similar (in TFS) when I publish a web application to our production server.

We do all our work in the DEV branch and when it is ready for release we then publish the site to the web server.  What I am after is a snapshot of the code that is currently running on our production server.

I realise that I could manually create a branch or label but am looking for a way to automate this.  I am looking to make the publishing procedure as simple as possible since we tend to publish frequently.

We do not have a release schedule but rather release whenever changes are completed and tested.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example where I modified the TFS build process to automatically create a branch and check the code into it.  Let me know if you have any questions.

http://www.codesmartnothard.com/2009/07/02/HowToBranchWithinInATFSBuild.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that.  I won't be using all of your solution but just knowing I can branch from the command line is probably all that I need.